# Films : Version doublée vs originale sous-titrée

Tags: france, cinéma

En France la version originale sous-titrée n'est pas répandue. Je sais qu'il en est de même en Allemagne et peut-être ailleurs. Cependant, ce n'est pas vrai pour tous les pays. Par exemple, le Royaume-Uni, la Suède, le Norvège, la Roumanie,  la Grèce ne pratiquent le doublage que pour les films s'adressant aux enfants.

Pourquoi les versions doublées sont alors plus répandues que les versions originales sous-titrées en France ? Pour quelles raisons regarder un film doublé (même un blockbuster américain) est devenu normal, voire entendu ?

Comment: Hmm, je trouve que c'est pas beaucoup de gens qui aiment lire des sous-titres pendant un film. Cependant la raison pour laquelle les anglais aiment lire et les européens non m'échappe.

Comment: C'est pas vraiment en relation avec la langue française, mais voici un article à ce sujet : http://www.slate.fr/story/18195/pourquoi-la-france-double-t-elle-tout-le-monde

Comment: Je pense que c'est en rapport au nombre de locuteurs de la langue. Ce n'est peut être pas "rentable" de doubler un film pour 5 millions (comme en Norvège), alors que je pense que ça l'est pour 65 millions de français ;)

Comment: Une hypothèse: le doublage réalisé pour le public français est de meilleure qualité que le doublage réalisé pour les publics qui préfèrent les sous-titres?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La raison est économique (et aussi en partie politique). Diffuser un film dans la langue du pays permet d'augmenter son audience potentielle. Le coût d'un doublage étant relativement fixe, plus la langue cible est répandue, plus l'amortissement du doublage sera rentable.

Ceci génère un cercle vicieux. Les français (de France) ne sont en général pas bons en anglais parce qu'ils n'ont quasiment aucune imprégnation avec cette langue (et encore moins avec d'autres langues étrangères) et sont donc moins attirés par des films en VOST.

Toutes les séries, les films, les émissions, les interviews sont doublés en français. Il y a peu ou pas de chaînes de télévision ou de radios en anglais. Il suffit de comparer le niveau d'anglais des canadiens francophones qui ont de leur côté une imprégnation forte avec l'anglais.

Au contraire, dans beaucoup de pays du nord ou de l'est de l'Europe, le niveau d'anglais est meilleur que celui des français car les films et séries sont diffusées en version originale, d'où une plus forte imprégnation des habitants dès leur plus jeune âge.

La situation évolue cependant avec la généralisation de la VM (version multilingue) avec laquelle il est possible de choisir la langue et les sous-titres (TNT, ADSL, etc.)

Un sondage [BVA-Presse régionale-Foncia de 2017](http://www.bva.fr/fr/sondages/les_francais_et_le_cinema.html) montre que plus d'un quart des français (27%) choisissent la VOST contre 71 % la VF. Le pourcentage s'élève à 36 % de VOST chez les 18-34 ans et à 54 % de VOST en Ile-de-France. Il faut donc relativiser le désintérêt des français pour les films en version originale.

Comment: Bien vu, j'avais pas pensé à voir la corrélation dans ce sens-là. Mais l'un entraîne l'autre, et même maintenant, on voit de plus en plus de séances en VO mais les gens n'y vont pas. Même quand ils ont le choix, les gens préfèrent la VF.

Comment: Merci pour les réponses et les commentaires. Peut-être les gens ne sont pas à l'aise lisant les sous-titres des VOST ou pas habitués.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Oui, l'un entraîne l'autre. C'est la définition du cercle vicieux...

Comment: @TeleportingGoat *Les gens n'y vont pas* est exagéré. Je ne regarde les film étrangers (qu'ils soient en anglais ou n'importe quelle langue) qu'en VOST, et quand c'est dans un cinéma, la salle est loin d'être vide.

Comment: Je plussoie cette réposne et le commentaire de jlliagre. @TeleportingGoat, c'est un cercle vicieux, et je pense néanmoins qu'il s'estompe peu à peu, la nouvelle génération tendant à en sortir. Ceci est montré par la statistique de la réponse. Les nouvelles technologies, les sites de streaming par exemple, proposant très facilement des sous-titres, ont un rôle majeur dans ce changement, tandis que la télévision traditionnelle ne le permettait pas.

Answer (score 2):

I would contest the facts as presented in the original post.  In France, the ratio of sub-titled vs. dubbed depends on where you are.  In Paris, back when I lived there, both were typically shown, and it may well have been the case that more please showed films "v.o." (version originale).  In smaller towns, they're more likely to show the film in only one format.  In the U.S., what is most marked is not a preference for subtitling (as asserted in the original post) but a distaste for anything not in English, whether dubbed or subtitled, which is why (outside the largest cities) you're more likely to see an American remake of a foreign film than the foreign film itself.

Answer (score -1):

Oui évidemment les français aiment voir les films en langue française pas en version originale parce qu'ils n'aiment pas faire l'effort a lire les sous-titrages ; d'autant qu'il y a possibilité de le voir en français, ce qui paraît plus confortable.
Contrairement à d'autres pays européens, il y a aussi la raison économique : plus tu tu traduis de films ou de séries, plus ça sera un bénéfice pour le secteur cinématographique.

Comment: Cette réponse est en partie fausse.  À la télévision depuis quatre ans en France (sauf sur la 3, qui s'y est mis plus tard) les séries télé (et les films à la télévision) le téléspectateur peut choisir entre la VF ou VOST.

Answer (score -2):

Pour moi la raison principale est que **les Français sont assez mauvais en anglais** de manière générale.

D'abord, pour beaucoup de gens, c'est un effort à faire de lire des sous-titres, et quand ils vont au cinéma pour se changer les idées ils n'ont pas envie d'avoir à faire des efforts.

Ensuite, l'immense majorité des films doublés en France sont des films en anglais (la quasi totalité venant d'Hollywood). Et de manière générale, c'est quand même plus agréable de regarder un film en anglais sous-titré quand on comprend un minimum l'anglais. Tant pis s'ils perdent du sens à la traduction ou s'il perdent une partie du jeu des acteurs. D'abord le gain de fluidité et de compréhension qu'apporte la traduction compense, et puis on ne se rend pas compte de ce qu'on perd tant qu'on ne compare pas avec la VO.

Donc si ça dépend beaucoup du niveau d'anglais, ça m'étonne assez peu pour le Royaume-Uni, ni pour la Suède et la Norvège qui sont assez bons en anglais. J'ai cru comprendre que la Roumanie aussi n'est pas mauvaise. D'après [ce classement](https://planificateur.a-contresens.net/classement_par_pays/EFEpi.html), tous ces pays ont un meilleur niveau en anglais que la France.

Évidemment il y a sûrement beaucoup de facteurs, mais je pense que le niveau d'anglais joue beaucoup.

Comment: C'est le contraire...

Comment: Le niveau linguistique n'est pas aussi corrélé selon moi. Il est tout à fait possible de regarder un film en japonais, en anglais, ou dans n'importe quelle langue, pourvu que l'on ait les sous-titres français avec. Je pense que c'est plutôt lié aux habitudes ou à des raisons économiques, comme le précise @jlliagre dans sa réponse et même si cela évolue, comme il l'a également précisé.

Comment: C'est, en partie, parce que les français regardent en VF qu'ils sont mauvais en anglais. Et non le contraire, ils regardent en VF parce qu'ils sont mauvais en anglais.